# About LDA model, I need a true expert to tell me that what is the real benefits of the Dirichlet prior?

Tags: machine-learning, dirichlet-distribution, topic-models

Well,you know ,the only difference between pLSI and LDA is that the latter has a Dirichlet prior,thus the number of model parameters do not increase with the size of corpus,and this avoid the overfitting problem in pLSI.Furthermore,having a prior in the level of documents is good for making inference when handling a unseen doc.

Plus,the Dirichlet distribution is conjugate to Multinomial distribution ,which makes it easy for computing the posterior.

However,personally,the aforementioned there advantages are not the most powerful  benefit of Dirichlet prior! I think when D.Blei introduced this hyperparameter,some other wonderful ideas might strike him.

So,who could tell me the hidden power of this Dirichlet prior?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question. The only reason a Dirichlet prior is used is because it's the multinomial distribution's conjugate prior, which makes computation of the posterior easier, and collapsed Gibbs sampling feasible.

There is nothing magic about this distribution, or David Blei for that matter.